# Sudden spike in pageviews in a WordPress site

Tags: seo, wordpress, traffic

A few days go I saw my "Pageviews" jump to an all time high....

- I did not add new content.
- I did not change or meddle with the
  WordPress plugins or themes
- I did not add edit or delete my site in
  Google Webmaster Tools

I am not complaining, just very curious why suddenly there's an increase?

See the attached picture:

[image: Statpress Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, there's really not enough information here to be able to answer this specifically. You should consider adding Google Analytics so you can see where the traffic is coming from.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool was that screenshot taken from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of many reasons:

- A high volume referrer included links to your site
- The pages contain content which has recently trended on social
  networks
- The analytics tracking is messed up ;)

Which analytics tools are you using? If you can establish a spike in traffic from a particular source (organic search/Direct/Facebook) you will most probably get the answer to your question